# c# / sqlite / out of memory / transaction / csv

Tags: c#, sqlite, csv, transactions, out-of-memory

How can i solve this problem?
Procedure is below.

1. Import csv file
2. Insert data to sqlite (1 million rows)

Exception is "System.Data.SQLite.OutOfMemoryException"
I used "beginTransaction" and "Commit"
And CSV file memory is 118MB
I tried everything. But I can't this problem

Here is my source code.
Please help.

```
OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
file.Filter = "(*.csv)|*.csv";
file.ShowDialog();

string filename = file.FileName;
string fileNameNoEx = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

for (int j = 0; j < ListBox.Items.Count; j++)
{
    if (fileNameNoEx.Equals(ListBox.Items[j]))
    {
        return;
    }
}

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:/sqlite");
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:/sqlite/SQLiteEx.db");
if (!di.Exists)
{
    di.Create();
}
if (!fi.Exists)
{
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("C:/sqlite/SQLiteEx.db");
}

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source = C:/sqlite/SQLiteEx.db;PRAGMA synchronous = OFF; PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;");
conn.Open();
string sql = "";

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
int i = 0;

using (SQLiteTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] cols = line.Split(',');
        string fieldName = "";
        string colData = "";

        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    fieldName = "'" + cols[0] + "' TEXT";
                }
                else
                {
                    fieldName = fieldName + ",'" + cols[j] + "' TEXT";
                }
            }
            sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + fileNameNoEx + "(" + fieldName + ");";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    colData = cols[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    colData = colData + "," + cols[j];
                }
            }

            sql = "INSERT INTO " + fileNameNoEx + " VALUES (" + colData + ");";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        i++;
    }
    tr.Commit();
}
sr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do all of the inserts inside a single Transaction?

Comment: Since the insert action doesn't rely on any other database data, I'm not sure there should be a transaction at all. Do remember transactions are made to store all changes to allow reverting or committing them all in one final command, so yes, all of it is saved in memory before that happens.

Comment: Is there reason why sqlcollect array is used? I believe this is the root cause of the OOM exception. Try removing it and give it a try. Let me know. FYI, there are other issues with your code, people already have raised it in the answers section. Pls consider them as well.

Answer (score 2):

I see many string concatenations and your code generates 1 million of `SQLLiteCommands`.

Have you tried to create a single `SQLLiteCommand` with parameters? You can change the values of the parameters in the loop (would also be better to prevent SQL-Injection - in case of attacks or *specials* characters in the CSV file).

For example:

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [myTable] ([Id], [name]) VALUES (@Id, @Name)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Id"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@name"));

    foreach(var row in csv)
    {
       cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = row.id;
       cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = row.name;

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with what you said, but this doesn't answer the question and the relevant part is only included as a link to an external site. This should be a comment, not an answer (for which you do not have the reputation yet, I know).

Comment: i understand.Nonetheless, trying to have a single sqlcommand could reduce significantly the amount of memory required. because actually, there are 1 million of SQLiteCommand instanciated

Comment: That's actually not a bad argument - and it would help with the SQL-Injection vulnerability of the current code. If you could work that into your answer (edit button at the bottom) and include the relevant code from the link (indent 4 spaces for code-markup) this could be a valid answer.

Comment: edit done (not very easy to indent the code) do you have something better that putting many spaces at the beginning of the rows ?

Comment: @Jean-SébastienPadoan Easiest way to do so is to copy the code into the editor of your choice (Notepad++, VS, etc.) and indent / unindent with Tab or Shift+Tab

Comment: I tried to create single 'SQLiteCommand' as you said. The conclusion is .... It works!! I learned a lot. Thanks to you Padoan.